# Qlik Sense Desktop Concerns

Tags: qliksense

I have a process to automate daily P&L monitoring. One year's worth of excel data worth of 5million rows. Can Qlik sense Desktop manage without server involvement?

I have more concerns regarding a Qlik Sense and would appreciate someone who is capable of Qlik Sense Desktop to get their expertise.

Answer (score 0):

From a data processing point of view there is no difference between QS Desktop and QS Enterprise. Both products are using the same engine in the background. The limitation will be on the machine resources. Since Qlik Engine is an in-memory tool the main resource will be the RAM. So more RAM - the better.

Broadly speaking 5 million rows should be fine on any laptop/desktop. But again it depends on the machine specs.

Let me know in the comments (or open another question. SO sometimes clear old comments) if you have any other questions.

Answer (score 0):

I have some experience in QlikSense Desktop edition and over the years have learnt quite a few things in it. The Desktop version uses the tenant (server) for verification since my organization has a Cloud SaaS version also running, apart from this, it works independently on your local machine.

Now for the processing speed, I would suggest that your system should have preferably 16GB Ram and an SSD drive. Keep your data files on the SSD. For processing the Excel sheets with a few million rows, I would suggest converting them to QVD files first, as they are pretty fast when it comes to processing and loading in comparison to Excel or CSV